# OCR returns "--“--mode=client --port=52085” and crashes

Tags: python, ocr

I am trying to run a OCR package known as Paddle OCR in Pycharm but even after successful installation of package I get following error after running the code and do not know how to resolve this :-

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
ocr = PaddleOCR(lang="korean")
```

Error :-

```
        usage: pydevconsole.py [-h] [--use_gpu USE_GPU] [--ir_optim IR_OPTIM]
                   [--use_tensorrt USE_TENSORRT] [--gpu_mem GPU_MEM]
                   [--image_dir IMAGE_DIR] [--det_algorithm DET_ALGORITHM]
                   [--det_model_dir DET_MODEL_DIR]
                   [--det_max_side_len DET_MAX_SIDE_LEN]
                   [--det_db_thresh DET_DB_THRESH]
                   [--det_db_box_thresh DET_DB_BOX_THRESH]
                   [--det_db_unclip_ratio DET_DB_UNCLIP_RATIO]
                   [--det_east_score_thresh DET_EAST_SCORE_THRESH]
                   [--det_east_cover_thresh DET_EAST_COVER_THRESH]
                   [--det_east_nms_thresh DET_EAST_NMS_THRESH]
                   [--rec_algorithm REC_ALGORITHM]
                   [--rec_model_dir REC_MODEL_DIR]
                   [--rec_image_shape REC_IMAGE_SHAPE]
                   [--rec_char_type REC_CHAR_TYPE]
                   [--rec_batch_num REC_BATCH_NUM]
                   [--max_text_length MAX_TEXT_LENGTH]
                   [--rec_char_dict_path REC_CHAR_DICT_PATH]
                   [--use_space_char USE_SPACE_CHAR]
                   [--cls_model_dir CLS_MODEL_DIR]
                   [--cls_image_shape CLS_IMAGE_SHAPE]
                   [--label_list LABEL_LIST]
                   [--cls_batch_num CLS_BATCH_NUM]
                   [--cls_thresh CLS_THRESH]
                   [--enable_mkldnn ENABLE_MKLDNN]
                   [--use_zero_copy_run USE_ZERO_COPY_RUN]
                   [--use_pdserving USE_PDSERVING] [--lang LANG]
                   [--det DET] [--rec REC] [--use_angle_cls USE_ANGLE_CLS]
     pydevconsole.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mode=client --port=61156
     Process finished with exit code 2
```

anyone has an idea how to move forward to resolve the error ?